# Import python projects to a HTML page

Tags: python, html

Supose I have a python game and I want to "post" it on a site like Friv that I am making. Is there any way
for me import the "game.py" to the "site.html" and it show when I enter the site? I made a search and found to use django, but I would need to pass all the html code that I already have to other aplication.

Answer (score 1):

The language of browsers is JavaScript.

There is a project called [PyJs](http://pyjs.org/) which translates Python code to JavaScript and is useful in your case that you want to run Python code inside web browsers.

Finally you can use your resulting JavaScript files to fill up your HTML page.

In addition to PyJs, there are numerous other projects that "run Python code in a browser" like [Brython](https://brython.info/). However, any of them have not been standardized and if you want a robust game in your browser, use JavaScript!

Answer (score 0):

There are number of projects that compile python into JavaScript in order to be run on browser.

Here are two links that might help

1. Web Browser Programming: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebBrowserProgramming
2. PyGame Trinket: https://trinket.io/features/pygame

Answer (score 0):

The way I integrate python code in an html is to use templating language like [jinja2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/) but if you want to write full python code in html then use need to use a transpiler like PyJS but since you want to integrate the same code in multiple program, why not use **[FLASK](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/)** it is much more easier.

and make an api. **Django** is an option but it has a **steep learning** curve. you can make the UI using HTML and get the data from python using API.